# Find a string between spaces

Tags: grep, logs

I was searching around the site and couldn't find a solution for the following, despite it's a simple thing. So let me share...

If you know a better solution, please share

I have the following log

**Content**

```
message 0956 5213649785 foobarfoobarfoobar foobar foobar foobarfoobar
message 2:1:0956 2:5:5213649785 foobarfoobarfoobar foobar foobar foobarfoobar
message 0989 5278956425 foobar foobarfoobar foobar foobar foobar
message 8:9:0989 6:1:5278956425 foobar foobarfoobar foobar foobar foobar
message 0856 9865452132 foobarfooba rfoobar foobar foobar foobar
message 7:4:0856 2:0:9865452132 foobarfooba rfoobar foobar foobar foobar
message 0989 2134687521 foob arfo obarfoo bar foobar foo bar foob ar
message 8:8:0989 9:0:2134687521 foob arfo obarfoo bar foobar foo bar foob ar
```

I want to get all those lines which have a numeric string with 12 chars between spaces

With this I could find the numeric string and the specific length

```
grep -E '[0-9]{12}' file.log
```

But how to get those that are between spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put spaces in the regexp where you want to match them.

```
grep -E ' [0-9]{12} ' file.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `[[:space:]]` expression

```
grep -E '[[:space:]][0-9]{12}[[:space:]]' file.log
```

Comment: `{10}` should be `{12}`